# Изменить filter hue-rotate в css через js

Tags: javascript, css

Почему не работает простая функции по смене фильтра?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Попробовать</button><br><br>

<img id="myImg" src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">

<script>
function myFunction() {
let out = '120deg';
  // Стандартный синтаксис
  
alert(out);
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.WebkitFilter = "hue-rotate(out)";
}
  
</script>
```

То есть фильтр не пременяется через переменную, если же просто поставить hue-rotate(120deg), то все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что это строка

```
 .... = "hue-rotate(out)";
```

а вам нужно передать туда значение из переменной

можно так, обратите внимание на кавычки обратные

```
`hue-rotate(${out})`
```

или так:

```
"hue-rotate(" + out + ")"
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь буду знать про синтаксис немного больше

Comment: @АлексейЩетинин - пожалуйста